# Unity not accepting some newer C# code

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, c#-6.0

I used to write my game in visual studio however it just happend to be way to weak to handle it and i decided to switch to unity and also take my code with me. In vs2015 i used C# 6 but i think unity is still on older version because it wont accept some of my lines as *proper* here are few examples

```
protected override double percentageIncrease { get; } = StatsIncreaments.MagicPowerIncreament;
```

this is really weird because it accepts auto properties with only `get` and `set` but this one is not recognized as proper.

Also any expression bodied functions are not tolerated as well :

```
public double CalculateExperience() => currentLevel * (currentLevel * 1.1) * 10;
```

Is there any way to make unity accept my code ?

Comment: Assigning values in `Awake` or `Start` instead of at declaration should work (if using a MonoBehaviour), otherwise use a constructor.

Comment: Thanks that seems to fix the first problem, but what about the expression bodied functions should i just change them into normal functions ?

Comment: If this is just a simple getter function you could also use a property.

Comment: I changed all of my properties with get and set to get value from the constructor now i get this error **percentageIncrease.get' must have a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. The property can be automatically implemented when you define both accessors**

Comment: are you aware UNITY USES AN OLD VERSION OF MONO. it is trivial to look at the manual for this.

Comment: I'm writing in visual studio 2015 if it matters.

Comment: you can instantly google answers here http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html

Comment: The error should go away when you add a `set`, because you try to assign a value without having a setter.

Comment: hopefully the whole question will go away  :)